# Get the temperature of the CPU/GPU using javascript?

Tags: javascript, electron

I was wondering if and how I'm able to read the temperature of the GPU in Javascript, for use in an Electron app. I kinda doubt that it's going to be doable and I can't find anything on the internet about it. Also I might need to read the CPU temperature, although that's less necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't really a question of what JavaScript can or can't do, as much as what the platform itself can do.  If you are writing JavaScript on the Node.js Platform, for example, you probably have hardware access.  If you are writing JavaScript on a Browser platform, not so much.  Electron is the platform in this question, so this is more about what Electron provides in it's API.

Comment: This looks like a promising package for your project: https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation.